# Job scheduling with Selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I made some scripts using selenium IDE. Is it possible to make selenium ide or "selenium-something" run some scripts according to a schedule ? If not, then is there any java code which can simply use some api and execute the scripts (ie something like -  SeleniumJava.runMyScript("enter_your_path_here")) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins) a try for that. One of the things it does well is launch processes (like your Selenium tests) according to a schedule.